# How can we minify JavaScript when it is export as module

Tags: javascript, import, export, es6-modules, minify

I created an 'indexScript.js' file and exported then I imported it in "index.js" file.
I would like to minify the entire code in the 'indexScript.js' only when I exported or imported. I mean the original 'indexScript.js' file should not be minified. Because I need the un-minified code for debugging. I only need minified code when it is exported or imported. Hopes my explanation is understandable. If not please comment me, I'll explain it more. The code what I am trying to achieve is as follows. Anyone have technique to make it possible. Thanks in Advance!

indexScript.js

```
let indexScript=()=>{
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
}
indexScript();

export {indexScript};
```

index.js

```
import {indexScript} from './includes/index-script.js';
```

Comment: Actually, this is not a programming question. Typically you've a developement copy of the site on a local server or in a cloud etc. Then you deploy the copy (or just changes to it) to your web server using specific deploying tools. During deploying, the files are minified, and the original code stays untouched. You've to choose deployment tools suitable for your project, then if you have a question about how to use the tools, you can ask here.

Comment: @Teemu I was looking for any ES6 features which will do the minifying process on the development

Comment: There's no such feature in JavaScript, which would minify files.

Comment: ES6 does not contain any features for minifying.  You must use external build tools to minify things in whatever build process you choose to use.  Typically one would create a non-minified version for local debugging and a minified one for final test and then deployment.  And, it goes without saying that exported properties should not have their names minified because the code doing the import must know their names.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your comments Teemu and jfriend